# Yii 2 initialize component

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to do what exactly Yii2 do with component in `config` file 
in yii `config`:

```
'someComponent'=>
[
    'class' => '\namespace\to\class',
    'param1' => 'somevalue',
    'param2' => 'somevalue',
]
```

How I can do that Yii do in my own class, give it an array of component file and then my class create and instance and initialize it?

EDIT:

Config file:

```
'payment' => [
            'class' => 'backend\modules\payment\Bank',
            'components' => [
                'service'  => [
                    'class' => 'backend\modules\payment\components\Service',
                    'adaptors'=>[
                        'BankMeli' => [
                            'class'=>'backend\modules\payment\adaptors\BankMeli',
                            'test'=>'1',
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Service Component:

```
namespace backend\modules\payment\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

class Service extends Component
{
    public $adaptors = [];
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $adaptors = new \stdClass();
        foreach($this->adaptors as $key=>$adaptor)
        {
            $class = $adaptor['class'];
            unset($adaptor['class']);
            $adaptors->$key = Yii::createObject($class,$adaptor);
        }
        $this->adaptors = $adaptors;
    }

    public function run()
    {

    }
}
```

Inner component (BankMeli) that need to get initialized:

```
namespace backend\modules\payment\adaptors;


use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

class BankMeli extends Component
{
    public $test;

    public function __construct($config = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
    public function init(){
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

var_dump(service->adapters) output :

```
object(stdClass)[61]
  public 'BankMeli' => 
    object(backend\modules\payment\adaptors\BankMeli)[72]
      public 'test' => null
      private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => null
```

---

SOLVED:

I passed param array inside another array and problem solved:

```
$adaptors->$key = Yii::createObject($class,[$adaptor]);
```

Comment: what do you need to do exactly? I didn't understand.

Comment: I need my component(service)  property(adapters)  (it has some typo just ignore it)   just initialized as a normal component with config array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Yii::createObject()` yii2 created component object with config in config file. It's like this:

```
Yii::createObject($config['class'], $config['otherParamsWithoutClass']);
```

Anything in yii2 extends `Object` class, in constructor we can enter config params. `param1` and `param2` should be public properties, or model should have getter and setters.

```
public function __construct($config = [])
{
    if (!empty($config)) {
        Yii::configure($this, $config);
    }
    $this->init();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, object is created but the properties not initialized,

Comment: You should use parent::__construct($config) in end your component constructor and extends `Object` or `Component`.

Comment: this is the code in class:
`public function __construct($config = [])  
    {  
        var_dump($config);  
        parent::__construct($config);  
        if (!empty($config)) {  
            Yii::configure($this, $config);  
        }  
        $this->init();  
    }  `

but $config is empty

Comment: Remove all after `parent::__construct($config);` and ensure that class extends `Component` or `Object`.

Comment: let me edit my question and add all codes there for better inspect